# Jupyterlab - find and replace globally ( all files and in all directories )

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub, jupyter-console

Is there any way to find and replace text string automatically in all folder's files? similar to what we get in sublime text, VS code etc

Answer (score 3):

You can install [`jupyterlab-search-replace`](https://github.com/jupyterlab-contrib/search-replace) extension, for example with pip:

```
pip install jupyterlab-search-replace
```

and the required `ripgrep`, for example on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install ripgrep
```

If you use a conda environment you can just install both with:

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab-search-replace ripgrep
```

For up-to-date installation instructions see [the GitHub repository](https://github.com/jupyterlab-contrib/search-replace) of the extension.

This extension requires JupyterLab 3 or newer.

[image: Demonstration]

Answer (score 1):

In JupyterLab you can open a terminal.  Depending on the OS you use, you can use the tools from that OS to do the job.  On Linux for example you can use `find` and `sed` to replace:

```
find path/to/folder -type f -exec sed -i 's/replace this/with this/g' {} \;
```

Other than that I do not think that this is a built-in functionality in JupyterLab.